# windows server 2012 crashed when trying to install windows phone 8 sdk

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-server-2012

I have an windows server 2012 machine , i installed visual studio 2012 and when i tried to install windows phone 8 SDK ,the server machine crashed .
The documentation of windows phone SDK 8 says that windows server 2012 is not supported
But Does installing windows phone sdk crash the system ? 
please help i have a 8 RAM and harddisk of 160 gb 
Am very new to server 2012,
Is there any other work around to install windows phone sdk on windows server 2012 . As i understand hyper-v feature is supported by the windows server 2012
I need to install windows SDK on windows server 2012, because i need to develop app for sharepoint mobility. 
please suggest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't install the SDK on Window Server 2012 - try creating a VM with Windows 8 and installing it there.

Comment: is there any work around other than creating VM as VMs are slow , tedious

Comment: you need Windows 8 Pro or higher OS edition for Windows Phone 8 development - so either VM or real PC with mentioned OS

Comment: but sever 2012 is higher than windows 8, if I am nt mistaken

Comment: It is different, not higher, and MS have decided that Win Phone 8 is for Windows 8 workstations, not servers.